# Justifying Comparing Coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

I am familiar with the straightforward result that if two polynomials of degree at most $n$ agree on $n+1$ values, then they must be equal. This reasoning tends to justify the method of comparing coefficients for polynomials.

More generally however, if it is known that, say, for any $x\in\mathbf R$,
$$a_1x+a_2e^x+a_3e^{-x}=b_1x+b_2e^x+b_3e^{-x},$$
where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb C$, what is it that allows us to conclude $a_i=b_i$ for $i=1,2,3$? Is it the fact that these functions are linearly independent when treated as members of an appropriate function space? Or is there a simpler way to justify this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the linear independence is the natural approach. On the other hand, you can prove that $a_2=b_2$ as follows:\begin{align}a_2&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_1x+a_2e^x+a_3e^{-x}}{e^x}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{b_1x+b_2e^x+b_3e^{-x}}{e^x}\\&=b_2.\end{align}By a similar method, you prove that $a_3=b_3$ and it is now easy to prove that $a_1=b_1$.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. It's the linear independency of your chosen functions which ensures the equality of the coefficients.

If you were to say

$$ a_1 \cosh(x) + a_2 \exp(x) + a_3 \exp(-x) =  b_1 \cosh(x) + b_2 \exp(x) + b_3 \exp(-x)$$

the equalities would $\textit{not}$ always hold, because $\cosh(x) = \frac{\exp(x) + \exp(-x)}{2}$ which introduces a linear dependency.